# Issues in time delay for RSS feed on full screen clock python

Tags: python, tkinter, rss, feedparser

I have designed a full-screen clock for my Raspberry Pi 3 Model B which runs on Raspbian but can also run on Windows. The whole point of the clock is to show the date, time, and a RSS feed on r/news (Reddit).

The news feed should stay on the screen for 5 seconds then change to the next one, and this process should go on forever until I exit. If I use `sleep()`, the clock stops. I have tried using threading, but it only works on the first loop, and then tries to show the next one, but returns to the previous one.

The clock and date work fine, it's just that I can't get the feed to stay on screen for 5 seconds and move on to the next one.

Code:

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] == 2:
    from Tkinter import *
else:
    from tkinter import *
from time import *
import datetime
import feedparser
root = Tk()
d = feedparser.parse('https://www.reddit.com/r/news/.rss')
def exitt():
 sleep(3)
 root.destroy()
time1 = ''
extra_time1 = ''
clock = Label(root, font=('calibri light', 150), bg='black', fg='white')
clock.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
extra_clock = Label(root, font=('calibri light', 45), bg='black', fg='white')
extra_clock.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
label_rss = Label(root, font=('calibri', 14), bg='black', fg='white')
label_rss.pack(fill=BOTH)
end = Button(root, text="Exit", font=('bold', 20), fg="white", 
bg='black', bd=0, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, 
highlightcolor='black', command=lambda:exitt(), height=0, width=0)
end.pack(fill=BOTH)
def rssfeeds():
 for post in d.entries:
     RSSFEED = post.title
     label_rss.config(text=RSSFEED)
     #sleep(5) <-- To prevent glitches but to keep my point
#rssfeeds()
def tick():
 global time1
 time2 = strftime("%H:%M:%S")
 if time2 != time1:
  time1 = time2
  clock.config(text=time2)
 clock.after(1, tick)
def ticki():
 global extra_time1
 extra_time2 = strftime("%A, %d %B %Y")
 if extra_time2 != extra_time1:
  extra_time1 = extra_time2
  extra_clock.config(text=extra_time2)
 extra_clock.after(1, ticki)
tick()
ticki()
w, h = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()
root.overrideredirect(1)
root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w, h))
root.focus_set() # <-- move focus to this widget
root.mainloop()
```

I have added the first few lines to make it easier to run this code if you are using Python 3 because feedparser can run on Python up to v.3.4.

Comment: Why do you have both `tick` and `ticki`? `tick` updates the hour, minute, second 5 times a second, but `ticki` updates the weekday, day, month, year every millisecond! Get rid of `ticki` and update `clock` and `extra_clock` in `ticki`. And you can use `.after` in a similar way to fetch your RSS feed stuff.

Comment: Also, why do you have `from tkinter import *` and `import tkinter as tk`? You never actually use `tk`, but you should. Get rid of that evil star import.

Comment: @PM2Ring I have tried using after, but it causes the same result as sleep.

Comment: I would also like to say that combining them causes the code to glitch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you want you need an "iterator", which is a type of object that can spit out one element at a time. For you I would recommend `itertools.cycle`, since it also loops back to the beginning after it's done. Remember in event driven programming (GUIs) you can't use a normal loop, you have to have an event fire the next action. The event you will use is set with `after`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
if sys.version_info[0] == 2:
    import Tkinter as tk
else:
    import tkinter as tk
from time import sleep, strftime
import datetime
import feedparser
from itertools import cycle


root = tk.Tk()
d = feedparser.parse('https://www.reddit.com/r/news/.rss')
post_list = cycle(d.entries)
def exitt():
    sleep(3)
    root.destroy()
time1 = ''
extra_time1 = ''
clock = tk.Label(root, font=('calibri light', 150), bg='black', fg='white')
clock.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
extra_clock = tk.Label(root, font=('calibri light', 45), bg='black', fg='white')
extra_clock.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
label_rss = tk.Label(root, font=('calibri', 14), bg='black', fg='white')
label_rss.pack(fill=tk.BOTH)
end = tk.Button(root, text="Exit", font=('bold', 20), fg="white",
bg='black', bd=0, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0,
highlightcolor='black', command=lambda:exitt(), height=0, width=0)
end.pack(fill=tk.BOTH)
def rssfeeds():
    post = next(post_list)
    RSSFEED = post.title
    label_rss.config(text=RSSFEED)
    root.after(5000, rssfeeds) # call this method again in 5 seconds
rssfeeds()
def tick():
 global time1
 time2 = strftime("%H:%M:%S")
 if time2 != time1:
  time1 = time2
  clock.config(text=time2)
 clock.after(1000, tick)
def ticki():
 global extra_time1
 extra_time2 = strftime("%A, %d %B %Y")
 if extra_time2 != extra_time1:
  extra_time1 = extra_time2
  extra_clock.config(text=extra_time2)
 extra_clock.after(1000, ticki)
tick()
ticki()
w, h = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()
root.overrideredirect(1)
root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w, h))
root.focus_set() # <-- move focus to this widget
root.mainloop()
```

Some more things to note:

- use 4 spaces for indenting (read PEP8 for more style recommendations)
- Do not use wildcard imports (`from module import *`), they lead to bugs and are also against PEP8.
- Use a shebang always, but especially on linux systems.
- move to classes and OOP as soon as you can to clean up the code.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer!

Comment: @TrooperZ you may also want to check out reddit.com/r/learnpython for beginner level questions.